# sapper exported application inconsistent behaviour

Tags: export, sapper

**Project setup**

I have a sapper application with a header containing 2 links rendered using `<a>` tags (page1 and page2). These `<a>` tags contain slug names (`page1`, `page2`).  Clicking on these links will go to the `[slug].svelte` page.

project structure

```
src/
  routes
     [slug].svelte
     _error.svelte
     _index.svelte
etc
```

I export my application using

```
npm run export
```

I can see the following is created in the export folder,

```
__sapper__
    export
        page1
            index.html
        page2
            index.html
```

Therefore showing the links are correctly crawled and the `[slug].svelte` has been used to create my 2 pages. If in Windows Explorer i double click on one of the `index.html` pages i see it has the correct content.

**My issue**

When I run my application with the following command as instructed by the sapper export, I see inconsistent behaviour.

`npx serve __sapper__/export`

It seems that to start off with when I do client side navigation and click on `page1` link, I see the contents of my `_error.svelte` page or in a similar application i get a blank page.  I do NOT the contents of the exported pages, i.e. `page1` or `page2` and the browser tab is showing a 500.

I do not understand why this would occur when I can see they exist in the export folder.

Other times when I try the same thing it works perfectly.

Does anyone else see inconsistent behaviour with sapper's export?

I am using the following versions

```
"sapper": "^0.28.0",
"svelte": "^3.17.3",
"svelte-loader": "^2.9.0",
```

I have also seen in another Svelte application of ours which has many more pages, that client side navigation causes the page to be generated.  But yet the export has already generated that page, so how come all client side navigation is not serving up the exported page.  It seems to me that export only serves up the first page and then every client navigation is built, which is a SSR site not a statically generated site

Comment: How are you running your application?

Comment: @JHeth Sorry I missed that out, I have updated the question

Comment: Have you tried using `npx serve __sapper__/export` as the docs say? https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#sapper_export

Comment: Sorry i meant `npx serve __sapper__/export`  i am getting all muddled up with build/dev/export!